# jQuery Table Row Filtering by Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm trying to filter table rows in an intelligent way (as opposed to just tons of code that get the job done eventually) but a rather dry of inspiration.

I have 5 columns in my table. At the top of each there is either a dropdown or a textbox with which the user may filter the table data (basically hide the rows that don't apply)

There are plenty of table filtering plugins for jQuery but none that work quite like this, and thats the complicated part :|

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a basic filter example http://jsfiddle.net/urf6P/3/

It uses the jquery selector :contains('some text') and :not(:contains('some text')) to decide if each row should be shown or hidden.  This might get you going in a direction.

EDITED to include the HTML and javascript from the jsfiddle:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#filter1').change(function() { 
        $("#table td.col1:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();
        $("#table td.col1:not(:contains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: This is a fairly efficient way of doing it but best of all, so little code :P Thanks

Comment: very nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Slightly enhancing the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460535/1369473) posted by **Jeff Treuting**, filtering capability can be extended to make it case insensitive. I take no credit for the original solution or even the enhancement. The idea of enhancement was lifted from [a solution posted on a different SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747204/1369473) offered by [Highway of Life](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463038/highway-of-life).

Here it goes:

```
// Define a custom selector icontains instead of overriding the existing expression contains
// A global js asset file will be a good place to put this code
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
  return $(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

// Now perform the filtering as suggested by @jeff
$(function() {    
    $('#filter1').on('keyup', function() {  // changed 'change' event to 'keyup'. Add a delay if you prefer
        $("#table td.col1:icontains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();  // Use our new selector icontains
        $("#table td.col1:not(:icontains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().hide();  // Use our new selector icontains
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, and I'm not sure about the performance, but an option would be to tag each column (in each row) with an id starting with a column identifier and then a unique number like a record identifier.

For example, if you had a column Produce Name, and the record ID was 763, I would do something like the following:

```
​​<table id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Album</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="artist-127">Red Hot Chili Peppers</td>
            <td id="album-195">Californication</td>
            <td id="genre-1">Rock</td>
            <td id="price-195">$8.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="artist-59">Santana</td>
            <td id="album-198">Santana Live</td>
            <td id="genre-1">Rock</td>
            <td id="price-198">$8.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="artist-120">Pink Floyd</td>
            <td id="album-183">Dark Side Of The Moon</td>
            <td id="genre-1">Rock</td>
            <td id="price-183">$8.99</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You could then use jQuery to filter based on the start of the `id`.

For example, if you wanted to filter by the Artist column:

```
var regex = /Hot/;
$('#table1').find('tbody').find('[id^=artist]').each(function() {
    if (!regex.test(this.innerHTML)) {
        this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of just by ID, what if I want to search every column in every row?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter specific column by just adding children[column number] to JQuery filter. Normally, JQuery looks for the keyword from all the columns in every row. If we wanted to filter only ColumnB on below table, we need to add childern[1] to filter as in the script below. IndexOf value -1 means search couldn't match. Anything above -1 will make the whole row visible.

```
ColumnA  |  ColumnB  |  ColumnC
John         Doe         1968
Jane         Doe         1975
Mike         Nike        1990
  $("#myInput").on("change", function () {
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $("#myTable tbody tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this.children[1]).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)              
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**step:1** write the following in .html file

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**step:2** write the following in .js file

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```