# jQuery :contains() selector uppercase and lower case issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My html looks like this

```
<input id="txt" value=""></input>

<div class="link-item">jK</div>
<div class="link-item">JFOO</div>
```

my js

```
$('#txt').keyup(function(){

    var txtsearch = $('#txt').val();
    var filt = $("div.link-item:contains('" + txtsearch +"')");

    $("div.link-item").css("display", "none")
        .filter(filt)
        .css("display", "block");

});
```

I'm looking to filter content dynamically on the client side. When I type a capital j, it only returns the second div whereas I want to get all div that contain j whether upper or lower case.

Comment: It is not a issue (if you meant that it returns the first div) and for your information you write an input like this: `<input id="txt" value="" />`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2196641/1114171

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can change the `.contains` filter to be case insensitive or create your own selector.

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

This creates a new selector: icontains (or you could name it insensitive-contains, or whatever suits your fancy).
It's usage would be the same as contains: `$('div:icontains("Stack")');` would match:

```
<div>stack</div>
<div>Stack</div>
<div>StAcKOverflow</div>
```

Or override the existing `.contains` filter:

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

With this in place,

```js
$("div:contains('John')");
```

would select all three of these elements:

```
<div>john</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>hey hey JOHN hey hey</div>
```

Comment: I think you should create a separate selector for this rather then overriding the default one.

Comment: you get my last upvote (though I'd recommend naming it containsInsensitive so you don't go overwriting built-in stuff)

Comment: won't m be a string with all of `:contains(foo)` that you'd have to strip that out manually?  Do the jQuery docs explain this function anywhere?

Comment: Never mind - I guess it passes an array - the link I was looking at was full of crap.  Really neat solution.  But *is* this documented anywhere?  *exactly* how the function to expr works ?

Comment: @Stefan I edited/added an option for either creating your own selector or overriding the default. Thanks!

Comment: Old post, but holy *crap* this is nice.  Thanks, man.  Wish I had found this a month ago.

Comment: just in case anyone has trouble with what is `a,i,m` in `function(a,i,m)` like me.. refer this http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, @AbdulHameed! Now I get why the m[3].

Comment: @AbdulHameed: The link is broken. Can you please add descriptive comments, thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Why not use the `filter` function, and pass in a function that uses a case insensitive regex?

```
var filteredDivs = $("div.link-item").filter(function() {
    var reg = new RegExp(txtsearch, "i");
    return reg.test($(this).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SMZNH/)

Comment: For me, because this is not easy to remember compared to `:contains` or `:icontains`

Comment: @OGSean But then you have to remember how to create the `:icontains` selector.

Comment: @Lukas yeah true, I guess I prefer the existing selector patterns in jQuery

Answer (score 11):

Here is my contribution, hope it helps :)

```
$('#txt').keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    $("div.link-item")
        .hide()
        .filter(':contains("' + query + '")')
        .show();
});
```

The [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is case sensitive.

> *The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks. **The text must have matching case to be selected**.*

Also created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2VK/) if someone would like to try it out.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, must have misread your question.

Found this jQuery expression at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278 to create a new selector that is **case insensitive** and I updated my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2VK/1/).

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
        .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this with a raw selector.  The `contains` selector is case sensitive and there doesn't appear to be a case insensitive version. I think the best approach is to use a filter that manually queries the object

```
var filt = function (unused) {
  $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(txtSearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
};
```

Comment: If you like to settle for core functions out of the box only... otherwise, extending jQuery with another non-case-sensitive selector seems pretty nice!