# Filtering Table rows using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I found a Jquery script that does the table filtering stuff based on input field. This script basically takes the filter, splits each word and filters table rows with each word. So at the end you'll have a list of rows that have all the words in the input field.

http://www.marceble.com/2010/02/simple-jquery-table-row-filter/

```
var data = this.value.split(" ");

$.each(data, function(i, v){
     jo = jo.filter("*:contains('"+v+"')");
});
```

Now, what I need is that instead of filtering rows that contains each of the words in the input field. I want to filter all the rows that contain at least one of the word in the input field.

One way I've tried is to take each filtered lists into an array...

```
  var rows = new Array();

 $.each(data, function(i, v){
     rows[i] = jo.filter("*:contains('"+v+"')");
 });
```

At this stage, I have to make a UNION of all the rows in "rows" array and show them. I'm lost on how to do that exactly.

Above script in action - http://marceble.com/2010/jqueryfilter/index.html?TB_iframe=true&width=720&height=540

If I type "cat six" in the filter, I want to show three rows.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/).

The idea is to filter rows with function which will loop through words.

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
//show the rows that match.
.show();
```

**EDIT:** Note that case insensitive filtering cannot be achieved using `:contains()` selector but luckily there's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function so filter string should be uppercased and condition changed to `if ($t.text().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) > -1)`. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/1362/).

Comment: i love this solution. very comprehensive and takes advantage of jquery's filter() method.

Comment: This helped me a load. I love how simplistic it is even though its so powerful. @nrodic is the real MVP

Comment: Works well, but it matches *any* rows that contain the latest term entered. Is there a way for it to search the results of the first term for the second term?

Comment: @Timmah - Do you want to show only rows that match ALL words? This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/1064/) might be what you need.

Comment: @nrodic - That's right, I asked **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137992/loop-sequentially-through-an-array-with-another-array-with-javascript/29139436)** and got a very similar answer, but thanks anyway

Comment: This is a great solution. Can you make it so it's not case sensitive?

Comment: I was able to find the workaround yesterday, which was somewhat like yours. Thank you @nrodic

Answer (score 30):

There's no need to build an array. You can address the DOM directly.

Try :

```
rows.hide();
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tXNQd/)**

### EDIT

To discover the qualifying rows without displaying them immediately, then pass them to a function :

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    var _rows = $();//an empty jQuery collection
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        _rows.add(rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')");
    });
    myFunction(_rows);
});
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXNQd/122/)

Comment: think I spoke too soon. Your answer addresses my question exactly but I need a bit more. I don't want to show the rows immediately as I find a matching value. I need to make a list of all those rows and pass them to another function.

Comment: After you've filtered and removed the filter, no result in given, whilst all of them should be displayed

Comment: Dane you're right - my demo doesn't address that aspect. Try [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/tXNQd/122/), in which an empty filter is handled as a special case.

Comment: Simple and clean. Any way to make it case INsensitive?

Comment: @RickSmith You have any idea to make this case insensitive? Cant figure it out

Comment: See this answer for a override for the filter, to make it case insensitive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747204/2214980

Answer (score 5):

based on @CanalDoMestre's answer.  I added support for the blank filter case, fixed a typo and prevented hiding the  rows so I can still see the column headers.

```
    $("#filterby").on('keyup', function() {
        if (this.value.length < 1) {
            $("#list tr").css("display", "");
        } else {
            $("#list tbody tr:not(:contains('"+this.value+"'))").css("display", "none");
            $("#list tbody tr:contains('"+this.value+"')").css("display", "");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I chose @nrodic's answer (thanks, by the way), but it has several drawbacks:

1) If you have rows containing "cat", "dog", "mouse", "cat dog", "cat dog mouse" (each on separate row), then when you search explicitly for "cat dog mouse", you'll be displayed "cat", "dog", "mouse", "cat dog", "cat dog mouse" rows.

2) .toLowerCase() was not implemented, that is, when you enter lower case string, rows with matching upper case text will not be showed.

So I came up with a fork of @nrodic's code, where

```
var data = this.value; //plain text, not an array
```

and

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var stringsFromRowNodes = $t.children("td:nth-child(n)")
    .text().toLowerCase();
    var searchText = data.toLowerCase();
    if (stringsFromRowNodes.contains(searchText)) {
        return true;
        }
    return false;
})
//show the rows that match.
.show();
```

Here goes the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/jumasheff/081qyf3s/

Comment: Added benefit, back-spacing in your version restores all values to the display.

Comment: Just a note for future readers: You can easily change the `$t.children()` selector from `"td:nth-child(n)"` to a class like `"filter-criteria"`. Then adding that class to each `<td>` limits which columns the filter searches.

Comment: `stringsFromRowNodes.contains` needs to be changed to `stringsFromRowNodes.includes`.  I made an edit to the code in the post to reflect this. (May be pending review)  I did not change the JSFiddle

Answer (score 4):

i have a very simple function:

```
function busca(busca){
    $("#listagem tr:not(contains('"+busca+"'))").css("display", "none");
    $("#listagem tr:contains('"+busca+"')").css("display", "");
}
```

Comment: Should be `tr:not(:contains`.

Answer (score 2):

tr:not(:contains(.... work for me

```
function busca(busca){
    $("#listagem tr:not(:contains('"+busca+"'))").css("display", "none");
    $("#listagem tr:contains('"+busca+"')").css("display", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

nrodic has an amazing answer, and I just wanted to give a small update to let you know that with a small extra function you can extend the contains methid to be case insenstive:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more approach :

```
value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#product-search-result tr").filter(function () {
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Beetroot-Betroot's solution, but instead of using contains, I used containsNC, which makes it case insensitive.

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
"containsNC": function(elem, i, match, array) {
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText ||
"").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
});
```