# Jquery Search - Case insensitive.. How i was ignore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The trouble is, if there is the word “Nabeel” with an upper case “N” and I search “n”, it wont find it. How can I make this script case insensitive?

```js
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val();
  $("a.recent_views.mainserach span.font").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text();
    if (s.indexOf(g) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="Enter name………">

<a class="recent_views mainserach" href=""><br>
  <span class="font">Nabeel</span><br>
  <span class="font">Ali</span><br>
  <span class="font">Faisal</span><br>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Make them to Lower case then search

```js
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("a.recent_views.mainserach span.font").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (s.indexOf(g) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="Enter name………">
<a class="recent_views mainserach" href=""><br>
  <span class="font">Nabeel</span><br>
  <span class="font">Ali</span><br>
  <span class="font">Faisal</span><br>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do with [`contains()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFx4myoKHUAhXENo8KHdm3BCwQFgg0MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fcontains-selector%2F&usg=AFQjCNH2j1jtaVuo01-dj3IK6jiXnzoGrw&sig2=7rxWJ2cNm0RBpaCBPf5rKg) jquery function .its better with index match .And case [`insensitive`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746882/jquery-contains-selector-uppercase-and-lower-case-issue) match

```js
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  if (val) {
    $("a.recent_views.mainserach span.font").hide()
    $("a.recent_views.mainserach span.font:contains(" + val + ")").show()
  } else {
    $("a.recent_views.mainserach span.font").show()
  }
})

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="Enter name………">

<a class="recent_views mainserach" href=""><br>
  <span class="font">Nabeel</span><br>
  <span class="font">Ali</span><br>
  <span class="font">Faisal</span><br>
</a>
```