# Bootstrap 4 cards filtering with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Someone has had a dig at this before, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. I'm trying to filter cards on Bootstrap 4 and when I apply a search query, it ends up hiding all my cards, instead of just the ones it should.

Hopefully anyone can help.

```
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('.card').show();
    var filter = $(this).val(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
    $('.card-deck').find('.card .card-body h4:not(:contains(" + filter + "))').parent().parent().addClass('d-none');
  })
```

Here's the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/8120104x/#&togetherjs=jTm0prUR4S

Comment: The fiddle doesn't include bootstrap or jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$('.card').show();` won't work because once `d-none` is added it overrides the `display:block` added by `$('.card').show();`. Each `keyup` should remove the `d-none` class instead...

```
$('#search').keyup(function (){
    $('.card').removeClass('d-none');
    var filter = $(this).val(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
    $('.card-deck').find('.card .card-body h4:not(:contains("'+filter+'"))').parent().parent().addClass('d-none');
})
```

[Working demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/KvTSAFv2bv)

Note: jQuery `:contains` [is case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746882/jquery-contains-selector-uppercase-and-lower-case-issue/8747204).

Comment: Right, that's why it didn't make sense. How do I make the query search insensitive?

Comment: I would've spent years trying to solve this whole issue. Thank you!