# Filtering bootstrap card visibility based on content inside card

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I can't figure out something that is probably quite simple to do. I have a grid with cards that look like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ books[book]['cover']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <span class="title"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white">{{ book }}</h5></span>
    <span class="author"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white author">{{ books[book]['author'] }}</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an input field called `search-authors` and want to hide cards that do not contain whatever the value of `search-authors` is.

I'm trying to use this:

```
            $("#search-authors").on("keyup", function() {
              var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $(".card *").filter(function() {
                  $(".card").css('display', 'none')
                  .filter(':contains(' + value + ')')
                  .css('display', 'block');
                });
            });
```

This isn't working the way I expect it to. For example, typing just `c` shows only cards which contain `c` but typing `co` hides cards that contain `co` and did show up correctly typing just `c`.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code.

- You need to select the `.card` elements, not their child elements, and hide/show them directly.
- Use the `input` event instead of `keyup`. The former allows people to paste content in with the mouse, the latter does not.
- You don't need to nest the `filter()` calls.
- You're using `filter()` like a loop, which is unnecessary. Call `filter()` directly on the `.card` collection and update the matching elements from there.
- `:contains` is case-sensitive by default, so converting the input to lowercase isn't enough. However, you can implement your own case-insensitive version of `:contains` (credit @HighwayOfLife in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747204/519413))

With all that said, try this:

```js
$.expr[':'].icontains = (a, i, m) => $(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;

$("#search-authors").on("input", e => {
  $(".card").hide().filter(`:icontains(${e.target.value.trim()})`).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-authors" />
<div class="card">
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ books[book]['cover']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <span class="title"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white">ABC Book 1</h5></span>
    <span class="author"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white author">DEF Author 1</h5></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ books[book]['cover']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <span class="title"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white">ABC Book 2</h5></span>
    <span class="author"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white author">DEF Author 2</h5></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ books[book]['cover']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <span class="title"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white">UVW Book 1</h5></span>
    <span class="author"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white author">XYZ Author 1</h5></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ books[book]['cover']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <span class="title"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white">UVW Book 2</h5></span>
    <span class="author"><h5 class="bg-dark text-white author">XYZ Author 2</h5></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and excellent reply! It solved my issue and I got a better understanding of how things work! :-)