# jquery filter based on button text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter

I woul like to ask for some help / advise.
I would like to filter all `<p>` which contain the button text.
I'm stucked a little bit.
THANK YOU for the support!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var button = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(".color").filter(function() {
            $(".color").toggle(jQuery(".color p").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(button) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button>Show All</button>
  <button>Green</button>
  <button>Red</button>
  <button>Blue</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Red Green</p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Green</p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Red Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Green Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>Red </p>
  </div>
  <div class="color">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p> Green</p>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains(_your_text_)` would help you if you want to get the inner text of the element. Since you are filtering the text but there are case sensitive from the text, so from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747204/7856807) we customize and replace the filtering function and it filters without the case sensitive.

[Check this out](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var button = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    
    $('.color p:contains('+ button +')').toggle()
    // do what u want to the element
        
  }); // end of click button
});

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me out with this one :)