# Search input with jquery filter works only with part of the word

Tags: jquery

I have two select inputs and a search field that filter some divs. The `select` inputs work as expected. The search field should show divs that contain the text in the search box, but it works only if, for example, "ane" but not "Jane".

Can someone here see the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide all divs initially.
  $('.col.kontaktpersoner').hide();

  // Show the corresponding divs when the user types in the search field and selects a department and/or location.
  $('#search-field, #departments, #locations').on('input change', function() {
    var searchTerm = $('#search-field').val().toLowerCase().trim();
    var department = $('#departments').val();
    var location = $('#locations').val();

    // Construct the selector for the corresponding divs.
    var selector = '.col.kontaktpersoner';
    if (department) {
      selector += '.' + department;
    }
    if (location) {
      selector += '.' + location;
    }

    // Find all divs that contain the search term.
    var filteredDivs = $(selector).filter(':contains("' + searchTerm + '")');

    // If there are no divs that contain the search term, then find all divs that contain the search term as a whole word.
    if (filteredDivs.length === 0) {
      filteredDivs = $(selector).filter(':contains(\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b)');
    }

    // If there are still no divs that contain the search term, then find all divs that contain the search term as a prefix.
    if (filteredDivs.length === 0) {
      filteredDivs = $(selector).filter(':contains("' + searchTerm + '%")');
    }

    // Show the filtered divs.
    filteredDivs.show();

    // Hide all other divs.
    $('.col.kontaktpersoner').not(filteredDivs).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="departments">
  <option value="">Select Department</option>
  <option value="sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
  <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
</select>

<select id="locations">
  <option value="">Select Location</option>
  <option value="new york">New York</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="search-field" placeholder="Search kontaktpersoner...">

<div class="col kontaktpersoner sales london">
  <p>John Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="col kontaktpersoner marketing london">
  <p>Jane Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="col kontaktpersoner engineering london">
  <p>Peter Parker</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not comparing the same *case*.

This line:

```
var searchTerm = $('#search-field').val().toLowerCase().trim();
```

means your search term of `Jane` becomes `jane` - and you do not have any rows with `jane` in, only `Jane`.

The simplest solution is to implement a case-insensitive `:contains` function, eg [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746882/jquery-contains-selector-uppercase-and-lower-case-issue/8747204#8747204)

Giving updated snippet:

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide all divs initially.
  $('.col.kontaktpersoner').hide();

  // Show the corresponding divs when the user types in the search field and selects a department and/or location.
  $('#search-field, #departments, #locations').on('input change', function() {
    var searchTerm = $('#search-field').val().trim();
    var department = $('#departments').val();
    var location = $('#locations').val();

    // Construct the selector for the corresponding divs.
    var selector = '.col.kontaktpersoner';
    if (department) {
      selector += '.' + department;
    }
    if (location) {
      selector += '.' + location;
    }

    // Find all divs that contain the search term.
    var filteredDivs = $(selector).filter(':icontains("' + searchTerm + '")');
    //console.log($(selector).length, filteredDivs.length);

    // Hide all related divs
    $('.col.kontaktpersoner').hide();

    // Show the filtered divs.
    filteredDivs.show();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="departments">
  <option value="">Select Department</option>
  <option value="sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
  <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
</select>

<select id="locations">
  <option value="">Select Location</option>
  <option value="new york">New York</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="search-field" placeholder="Search kontaktpersoner...">

<div class="col kontaktpersoner sales london">
  <p>John Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="col kontaktpersoner marketing london">
  <p>Jane Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="col kontaktpersoner engineering london">
  <p>Peter Parker</p>
</div>
```

---

A couple of additional notes:

If you hide all then only show the ones you want, it will be atomic (appear as one), so you don't need the `.not(filtered)`

```
$('.col.kontaktpersoner').hide();
filteredDivs.show();
```

If the searchTerm doesn't appear anywhere in the text (your first check) then. by definition, it won't appear as a whole word or prefix either - so you don't need those checks.